# How to separate words separated by tabs in pythond

Tags: python

My file look that:

```
abc 1
bca 2
```

How to get texts(abc and bca) and append to array and get numbers and append to another array?
I made this:

```
plik = open("testcase.txt", "r")
imie = []
dlugosc = []
for line in plik:
    for word in line.split():
        imie.append(word)
```

Now when i print "imie" that shows everything.

Expected output:

```
plik = ['abc', '1', 'bca', '2']
imie = ['abc', 'bca']
dlugosc = ['1', '2']
```

Comment: What should output be?

Comment: when in for loop print(imie) that should show only abc and bca. When for loop print(dlugosc), obly 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this to check digit

```
a_string = "abc 1 bca 2"
numbers = []
for word in a_string.split():
    if word.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(word))

print(numbers)
```

OUTPUT : [1,2]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could even do this in a one-liner: `map(lambda x:int(x), filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),  "abc 1 bca 2".split()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a seperator in your call to `split()`. Something like `split('\t')` should do the trick.

Comment: doesnt work. When i print x in `for x in imie` that print for me: ['abc 1\n', 'bca 2']
['abc 1\n', 'bca 2']`

Answer (score 0):

You want to append the words after splitting into separate lists -

```py
imie = []
dlugosc = []
third_list = []
for line in plik:
    for word1, word2, *_ in line.split():
        imie.append(word1)
        dlugosc.append(word2)
        third_list.append(_)
```

Comment: doesnt work. Error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Which means some of your lines have more than one whitespace character. I have edited my answer for such a case, but make sure you check the contents of the third list to see what you are missing